# How to reduce specific text size in text animation?

Tags: html, css

I have created a text sliding animation that has a fixed text (SM) and two 'LI's that will slide and replace eachother (ART and allART). What I need is for "all" from SMallART to be in a smaller size.

```css
body {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #F2F2F2;
}

.content {
  width: 537px;
  font-size: 62px;
  line-height: 80px;
  font-family: 'Muli';
  color: #FE642E;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -40px;
  margin-left: 130px;
}

.visible {
  float: left;
  font-weight: 800;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 80px;
}

p {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-left: 101px;
  text-align: left;
  list-style: none;
  animation: 6s linear 0s normal none infinite change;
  -webkit-animation: 6s linear 0s normal none infinite change;
  -moz-animation: 6s linear 0s normal none infinite change;
  -o-animation: 6s linear 0s normal none infinite change;
}

ul li {
  line-height: 80px;
  margin: 0;
}

@-webkit-keyframes opacity {
  0% {
opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes opacity {
  0% {
opacity: 0;
  }

  50% {
opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes change {
  0% {
margin-top: 0;
  }

  15% {
margin-top: 0;
  }

  25% {
margin-top: -40px;
  }

  35% {
margin-top: -60px;
  }

  45% {
margin-top: -80px;
  }

  55% {
margin-top: -80px;
  }

  65% {
margin-top: -80px;
  }

  75% {
margin-top: -60px;
  }

  85% {
margin-top: -40px;
  }

  100% {
margin-top: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes change {
  0% {
margin-top: 0;
  }

  15% {
margin-top: 0;
  }

  25% {
margin-top: -40px;
  }

  35% {
margin-top: -60px;
  }

  45% {
margin-top: -80px;
  }

  55% {
margin-top: -80px;
  }

  65% {
margin-top: -80px;
  }

  75% {
 margin-top: -60px;
  }

  85% {
margin-top: -40px;
  }

  100% {
margin-top: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<div class="content">
  <div class="visible">
    <p>
      SM
    </p>
    <ul>
      <li>ART</li>
      <li>allART</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

So,how to reduce only the "all"text size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try defining a parent div ( for the general paragraph styling ), and a child div ( for a specific paragraph styling), and you can achieve your desired functionality, try this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="big-text">sm<div class="small-text">all</div>art</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.full-text {
    display:inline;
    font-size:22px;

}

.small-text {
    display:inline;
    font-size:10px;

}
```

The **Jsfiddle**:

[Differnet Sizes](https://jsfiddle.net/rxbLq91p/5/)